# jqGrid visibility issues

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

jqGrid and IE8 are not making friends... (
 the jqgrid is invisible in the IE, sometime when the mouse is over it, it appears, but still after sec it disappears.

in FF, Chrome, Opera it works fine.

is there a good explanation for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the guys that have the same problem. 
when the jqGrid is in another in a `<table>`, than u have the displaying problems in IE

> **EDIT**

```
  <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <%Html.RenderPartial("FilterForm");%>
            </td>
                <table id="GRID" class="scroll">
                </table>
                <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align: center;">
                </div>
        </tr>
</table>
```

in this case the jqGrid will behave realy strange in IE.

Comment: I am confused... can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

jQGrid works fine for me in IE8

Is `HiddenGrid` set to `true`?

[Documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options)

Comment: if it was true than i wouldn't see it in FF and Chrome